# Debezium with kafka or only embedded-Debezium?

Tags: java, apache-kafka, osgi, apache-karaf, debezium

Can someone tell me what is the difference between using embedded Debezium (without kafka) with an osgi bundle and using Debezium with kafka? I can't find a lot about Debezium in the internet.

Comment: https://medium.com/groww-engineering/moving-from-hibernate-envers-to-debezium-bae4856c0e1b

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With Kafka (Connect) you gain a great level of fault-tolerance and scalability. Check out [the documentation](http://debezium.io/docs/embedded/) of the embedded mode for a detailed description of its trade-offs.

Answer (score -2):

Embedded Engine will not guarantee Fault Tolerance and Limited Scalability.